# How to figure out when k means converges for tf idf?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means, tf-idf, convergence

I am fairly new with working with text data.

I have a data frame of about 300,000 unique product names and I am trying to use k means to cluster similar names together. I used sklearn's tfidfvectorizer to vectorize the names and convert to a tf-idf matrix.

After I transformed it to a sparse matrix I fit k means with 5-10 clusters but I do not know if I am converging.

How can I figure this out?

Comment: There should be a warning that prints out if it doesn't converge if memory serves correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/51a765a/sklearn/cluster/k_means_.py#L814) the attribute `n_iter_` should hold the number k-means iterations. If `n_iter_ < max_iter`, then the algorithm converged within the given tolerance.

If what you are trying to accomplish is to determine the optimal number of clusters, you can use the [elbow method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elbow_method_(clustering)) with the `inertia_` attribute.